# How to break StringBuilder thread safety(example unsafe code with great chance to be broken)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

As I know `StringBuilder` is not threadsafe.

I want to write example of break StringBuilder with data race.

my code:

```
public class Task4 {
    static StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
    static long N = 1000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyStringBufferThreadReader myStringBufferThreadReader = new MyStringBufferThreadReader(stringBuilder);
        MyStringBufferThreadWriter myStringBufferThreadWriter = new MyStringBufferThreadWriter(stringBuilder);
        new Thread(myStringBufferThreadReader).start();
        new Thread(myStringBufferThreadWriter).start();
    }
}

class MyStringBufferThreadReader implements Runnable {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    public MyStringBufferThreadReader(StringBuilder stringBuffer) {
        this.stringBuilder = stringBuffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Task4.N; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("READ:  " + stringBuilder);
        }
    }
}

class MyStringBufferThreadWriter implements Runnable {
    static StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    public MyStringBufferThreadWriter(StringBuilder stringBuffer) {
        this.stringBuilder = stringBuffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Task4.N; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            stringBuilder.append(i);
            System.out.println("WROTE: " + stringBuilder);

        }
    }
}
```

Did I do something wrong to break StringBuilder or I just lucky and potentially I can see problem?

Comment: Well, you are using the thread-safe `StringBuffer` throughout your entire code, so that’s unlikely to exhibit the fact that `StringBuilder` is not thread safe. To show that, the minimum you have to do is to use `StringBuilder`. Nevertheless, there is no guaranty that unsafe code exhibits problems anyway.

Comment: you can't break `StringBuilder` because your code is using `StringBuffer`

Comment: Obvious wrong thing: you're not using any StringBuilder. What are you trying to prove exactly?

Comment: @JB Nizet I want to write example which will works correctly with StringBuffer and incorrect with StringBuilder

Comment: @cahen Yes, but now it works as well

Comment: _I want to write example which will works correctly with StringBuffer..._  Then you will have to start by defining what "correct" means.  Probably it means, "(1) every string that my program adds to the buffer/builder will appear as a substring of the final result, (2) no part of any added string will be duplicated in the final result, (3) nothing will appear in the final result that was not added, and (4) it won't crash or throw any exception either when add() is called, or when toString() is called.

Comment: Forgot (5):  If some thread A adds string X and then adds string Y, then X will appear before Y in the final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks –  @Vivin Paliath

```
public class Task4 {
    static StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
    static final StringBuilder SEPARATOR = new StringBuilder("/");

    static long N = 1000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyStringBufferThreadReader myStringBufferThreadReader = new MyStringBufferThreadReader(stringBuilder);
        MyStringBufferThreadWriter myStringBufferThreadWriter = new MyStringBufferThreadWriter(stringBuilder);
        new Thread(myStringBufferThreadReader).start();
        new Thread(myStringBufferThreadWriter).start();
        new Thread(myStringBufferThreadReader).start();
        new Thread(myStringBufferThreadWriter).start();
    }
}

class MyStringBufferThreadReader implements Runnable {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    public MyStringBufferThreadReader(StringBuilder stringBuffer) {
        this.stringBuilder = stringBuffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Task4.N; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("READ:  " + stringBuilder);
        }
    }
}

class MyStringBufferThreadWriter implements Runnable {
    static StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    public MyStringBufferThreadWriter(StringBuilder stringBuffer) {
        this.stringBuilder = stringBuffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Task4.N; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("WROTE: " + stringBuilder.append(i).append(Task4.SEPARATOR));

        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
READ:  
WROTE: 0/
WROTE: 0/0/
READ:  0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
READ:  0/0/
WROTE: 0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/1
WROTE: 0/0/11
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
READ:  0/0/11/
WROTE: 0/0/11/2/ 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
WROTE: 0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
WROTE: 0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /
WROTE: 0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/
WROTE: 0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/
WROTE: 0/0/11/2/ /3/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5
WROTE: 0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
WROTE: 0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/
WROTE: 0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6/ 
WROTE: 0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 
WROTE: 0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/
WROTE: 0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
READ:  0/0/11/2/ /3/4/4/5/5/6// 7/7/
....
```

Comment: Yup - previously you only had one thread modifying state, so there was no real chance of state getting corrupted. The only way you will see a problem is if you have two threads modifying state on a non-threadsafe object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple test case:

```
public class test {
    static boolean running = true;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
          while (running) sb.append("test");
        }}).start();
        Thread.sleep(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) sb.append("hello");
        running = false;
        System.out.println(sb.toString().replace("test", "").replace("hello", ""));
    }
}
```

- It creates a shared StringBuilder
- It starts a new thread, which writes `test` to the StringBuilder until `running` is set to false.
- The main thread then sleeps for 10ms to give the thread time to start.
- The main thread then writes `hello` 1000 times to the StringBuilder.
- running is set to false, stopping the new thread (not very well)
- The StringBuilder is converted to a string, which is then stripped of the words `hello` and `test`.

If StringBuilder were thread-safe, no writes would collide with each other, and the output would be a blank string.

Because StringBuilder is *not* thread-safe, instead it prints several random smashes of "hello" and "test", e.g.

sthellhellhelloohellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellooohelloohellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellohellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhelloohellhellhellooooohellhellhellhelloohellhellhelloohellhelloteslooohellhelloooooooooooooooooooooohellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellooooooooohellhellhellhellhelloohestoooohellhellhellhellhellohelloohellhelloohellhellhell

Conclusion: having two threads write the same StringBuilder at the same time means they interfere with each others writes.